# Wait until dynamically added CSS file loads before performing action

Tags: jquery

I'm using this code to dynamically load an external css file, however I would like to wait until the css loads before performing another action, eg like showing some HTML.

```
$(document).on('click', '#game', function(e){   
    $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+myStylesLocation+'" >')
       .appendTo("head");
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ something like this.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use primitive `$.ajax` for this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: myStylesLocation,
    beforeSend: function() {
       // start animation
    }
    success: function(data) {
       $('<style type="text/css">' + data + '</style>').appendTo("head"); // append CSS
       // end animation
    }
});
```

Comment: Can I put that within my click function?